# Is there any way to make the width of a div element the same as the largest width of its children element in html?

Tags: html, css

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="latest-text">
    <p id="text-wrapper">
      <span style="display: inline-block;" id="title">ABFDFDFJEKJRKEREJRKE</span>
      <span style="display: inline-block;" id="subtitle">GJKJGKEJKEJFKAJKEJRE</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to make the width of the `#text-wrapper` element the larger width of `#title` or `#subtitle element`, but it seems that its width is always the same as the `#latest-text` element. Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Someone will surely tell you how to do this, but it seems you're approaching your DOM structure the wrong way. If these are indeed a title and subtitle they should not be *inside* a paragraph, and should be an `<h1>` and `<h2>` (or 2 and 3, etc., as appropriate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Set one of the spans to block, and the parent p tag to inline-block. Let the second span be inline.

```
<div id="latest-text">
  <p id="text-wrapper">
    <span id="title">ABFDFDFJEKJRKEREJRKE long, very long, very long</span>
    <span id="subtitle">GJKJGKEJKEJFKAJKEJRE</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#text-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

span#title {
  display: block;
}
```

See Dabblet: http://dabblet.com/gist/4694336

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to set the width of "text-wrapper".  First run a test on the width of "title" and "subtitle" to find out which is larger then assign the width of the larger one to "text-wrapper"

You can use JavaScript to get the width dynamically. Change the text for title and subtitle in the example and watch the text-wrapper get bigger or smaller.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script language="javascript">

function setwidth()
{
    var wrapper=document.getElementById('text-wrapper').clientWidth;
    var title=document.getElementById('title').clientWidth;
    var subtitle=document.getElementById('subtitle').clientWidth;

    if (title>subtitle)
        document.getElementById('text-wrapper').style.width=title;
    else
        document.getElementById('text-wrapper').style.width=subtitle;
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="setwidth()">

<div id="latest-text">
<p style="border:1px solid red;" id="text-wrapper">
This is the text-wrapper text 
<p>
  <span style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid yellow;float:none;" id="title">ABFDFDFJEK</span>
  <p>
  <span style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid blue;" id="subtitle">GEGJKJGKEJKEJFKAJKEJRE</span>
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is I dont know the width of each child element in advance. So I cannot hardcode the width of text-wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar question was answered here where the user was trying to set the width of a div by the span inside it.  See if this helps you.

[How to set width of DIV to span with text inside it (so not fixed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013520/how-to-set-width-of-div-to-span-with-text-inside-it-so-not-fixed)

Answer (score 0):

If you put `block` elements inside an `inline-block` element the inline-block will expand to fit the widest of the blocks within it.

```
<h1>Original Structure</h1>
<div id="latest-text1">
    <p id="text-wrapper1">
      <span style="display: inline-block;" id="title1">ABFDFDFJEKJRKEREJRKE</span>
      <span style="display: inline-block;" id="subtitle1">GJKJGKEJKEJFKAJKEJRE</span>
    </p>
</div>

<h1>Same, but using <code>block</code></h1>
<div id="latest-text2">
    <p id="text-wrapper2">
      <span style="display: block;" id="title2">ABFDF DFJEKJ RKER EJRKE</span>
      <span style="display: block;" id="subtitle2">GJKJ GKEJKEJF KAJKEJRE</span>
    </p>
</div>

<h1>Restructured as HTML5</h1>
<p>This also gets rid of inline styles, which are a leading cause of nightmares.</p>
<section id="latest-text3">
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>ABFDF DFJEKJ RKER EJRKE</h1>
            <h2>GJKJ GKEJKEJF KAJKEJRE</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header>
    <article>
        <p> ... the ... first ... paragraph ... </p>
        <p> ... the ... second ... paragraph ... </p>
    </article>
</section>
```

The `<hgroup>` isn't strictly necessary but it does make the most semantic sense.

And the CSS

```
#latest-text1, #latest-text2, section#latest-text3 {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#latest-text1 {
    background-color: #f0f0ff;
}
#latest-text2 {
    background-color: #f0fff0;
}
section#latest-text3 {
    background-color: #fff0f0;
}
#latest-text3  {
    display: inline-block; /* THE IMPORTANT ONE */
}
```

Most of that CSS is just to help visualize the whole thing, at http://jsfiddle.net/J3NzC/

The HTML5 could be redone as HTML4 by using `<div>` with appropriate classes, for example by using `<div class="section">` and `<div class="hgroup">`